# need help finding the derivative using chain rule

Tags: multivariable-calculus, partial-derivative

Suppose $\psi(x,y)=\phi(x+y,xy)$ find $\frac{\partial^2 \psi}{\partial y \partial x}$

My attempt:
I think this must be an application of the chain rule.  Do first I need to take the derivative with respect to y, and then follow that up with a derivative of x?  I am a little confused about how to take a derivative of a function of x and y equivalent to another function of x and y.  I tried looking for some examples similar to this one but was unsuccessful.

Comment: The most common meaning of $\dfrac{\partial^2 \psi}{\partial y \partial x}$ is that you first differentiate with respect to $x$ and then with respect to $y$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Hint**

Write $u(x,y)=x+y$ and $v(x,y)=xy.$ Then, we get the partial with respect to $x$ of $\psi(x,y)=\phi(u(x,y),v(x,y)).$ We have

$$\frac{\partial \psi}{\partial x}=\frac{\partial \phi}{\partial u}\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}+\frac{\partial \phi}{\partial v}\frac{\partial v}{\partial x}.$$

(Note that $\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}=1$ and $\frac{\partial v}{\partial x}=y.$)

Can you continue from here? That is, can you get $\frac{\partial}{\partial y}\frac{\partial \psi}{\partial x}?$

Comment: so $\frac{\partial \psi}{\partial x}=\frac{\partial \phi}{\partial u}+v\frac{\partial \phi}{\partial v}$ and then taking this with respect to y gives $\frac{\partial}{\partial y}(\frac{\partial \psi}{\partial x})=\frac{\partial}{\partial y}(\frac{\partial \phi}{\partial u})+\frac{\partial}{\partial y}(v\frac{\partial \phi}{\partial v})$

Comment: Well, it should read $\frac{\partial \psi}{\partial x}=\frac{\partial \psi}{\partial u}+y\frac{\partial \psi}{\partial v}.$ But you are right. This is the way.

Comment: Ok just bear with me a little longer, for instance do I need to use the product rule for the second term?  $\frac{\partial}{\partial y}(v \frac{\partial \phi}{ \partial v})=(\frac{\partial v}{\partial y})(\frac{\partial \phi}{ \partial v})+(v)(\frac{\partial phi}{\partial v})$

Comment: @JBF Yes. You need to derive a product.

Comment: Thanks I think something like this $\frac{\partial}{\partial y}(v \frac{\partial \phi}{ \partial v})=(\frac{\partial v}{\partial y})(\frac{\partial \phi}{ \partial v})+(v)(\frac{\partial \phi}{\partial v \partial y})$

Comment: @JBF In $v\frac{\partial \phi}{\partial v}$ you have to write $y\frac{\partial \phi}{\partial v}.$ Then, $$\frac{\partial}{\partial y}\left(y\frac{\partial \phi}{\partial v}\right)=\frac{\partial \phi}{\partial v}+y\frac{\partial}{\partial y}\left(\frac{\partial \phi}{\partial v}\right)=\frac{\partial \phi}{\partial v}+y\frac{\partial^2\phi}{\partial u\partial v}\frac{\partial u}{\partial y}+y\frac{\partial^2\phi}{\partial v^2}\frac{\partial v}{\partial y}.$$